# How do remove focus from inputs only on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on mid/large scale angularjs application. I have views that load in different styles according to whether a user is coming from a mobile or desktop device.

My problem is the auto-focus that is set using angular. While on desktop, it is beneficial, on mobile it's a bad user experience. How can I remove the auto-focus on input fields ONLY on mobile devices.

I'm utilizing simple if else statement to dictate which view to load. Is there a way to set focus = false when loading the mobile view?

```
//Detect Mobile Switch Refill List To Grid
if(window.innerWidth <= 800) {
    $scope.view = "MobileAccount";
} else {
    $scope.view = "DesktopAccount";
}
```

Comment: where are you trying to set the focus?

Comment: The focus is set in the view. <input name="blah" focus="true"/> I just want to make focus false on mobile only. Stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Just had to add the window.innerWidth to my if statement in the focus directive.

```
angular.module('App.Directives').directive('focus', function($timeout) {
return {
    scope: {
        trigger: '@focus'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {
            if (value === "true" && window.innerWidth >= 800) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    element[0].focus();
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```